# c++ linux access an object from a method

Tags: c++

HI,

How can I define an object in a method?

```
std::string method(std::string name, &pointer_to_any_class)
{
//code
}?
```

if I have a Class like `Class *x= new Class();` 
Can i have method like `Method("me",*x);`?

```
Class_me *y= new Class_me(); 
method("hey",*y);//will this mean that &pointer_to_any_class is a pointer to Class_me?
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "pointer to any class" in C++.

Comment: You should state what you are trying to do. Note that C++ is not a dynamic language, and that means that you cannot create new types, and that there is no such thing as `Class`

Comment: you need to pick up a good C++ book and try to understand how to pass arguments to functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Class_me` is derived from `Class` then it will work:

```
class Class
{
    ...
}

class Class_me : public Class
{
    ...
}

std::string method(const std::string &name, Class *cls)
{
    ...
}

Class *x = new Class();
Class_me *y = new Class_me();

method("me", x);
method("hey", y);
```

Comment: no,it's not derivated from Class. I have a class Class{... class Class_me{....}*class_me}*class;

Comment: i would like to create an object.i don't know how to do it. I mean I need an object as parameter in the method(std::string &name, ???);

Comment: You will have to derive them from a common ancestor if you want to use a single method to work on multiple class instances.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A function template can accept a variety of types that need not be related to each other:

```
template<typename T>
std::string
method(std::string const& name, T& t)
{
    // here t is a reference to type T
    return "";
}

Class x;
Class_me y;
method("me", x) // calls method<Class>
method("hey", y) // calls method<Class_me>
```

I couldn't have the template do anything useful because your question is too vague (also your `method` is not a method).